Unexpected Operator
Am learning Linux, I tried to execute this script, but am getting the error saying that "-gt: unary operator expected"
num=$5


if [ $num -gt 10 ]

then

        echo "greater than 10"
else

        echo "lesser than 10"
fi

Could anyone please help me with this issue? I want to pass an argument to the script which contains the number to be handled.
//Thanks

What did you pass as 5th parameter to your script?

To num, you assign $5, which is the – of course undefined – fifth argument of the script. So, the substitution turns out to be if [ -gt 10], which is not good. So you should assign simply 5 to num, the following way:
num=5

if [ $num -gt 10 ]

then

        echo "greater than 10"
else
        echo "lesser than 10"
fi

Update: it seems that the goal was to get the first argument of the script. In that case, neither $5 nor 5 will work, $1 should be used:
num=$1

if [ $num -gt 10 ]

then

        echo "greater than 10"
else
        echo "lesser than 10"
fi




@Zh ,Why do we have to use $1? not any other number? and why the $ symbol to be used?
Could  you please explain me?

This is how bash treats arguments to the script or a function; they are numbered 1 ... however many. (It gets tricky to access them past 9, you'll have to shift). Shell variables start with a $ when you access them, but don't have the $ when you set them. You should probably find a basic tutorial for the shell you're using. Also look into shellcheck.net, it would probably suggest you quote your variables (i.e., use if [ "$1" -gt 10 ] so that an undefined variable isn't a syntax error. Or you could use set -u so that undefined variables fail noisily.

Hi Robert,
Sure I will check the shellcheck.net,  Thank you !

Plus of course that should be echo "less than or equal to 10"
